# Condition for perfect matching in bipartite graphs

Tags: graphs

Let $G = (S, T, E)$ be a bipartite graph without isolated vertices.

For each edge $e ∈ E$, $e = st$ (where $s ∈ S$, $t ∈ T$), the inequality
$d_G (s) ≥ d_G (t)$ holds. Prove that there is a matching in $G$ saturating all
of $S$'s vertices.

Comment: What is a *peak*? A vertex? Also, by *coupling* do you mean a matching? Try to use standard English terminology.

Comment: This seems to be a purely mathematical question with no computational content.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure whether I understand the statement of the problem.  Is $G$ a directed graph?  Undirected graph?  What does it mean to saturate all of $S$'s vertices?  Can you edit the question to specify this?  2. What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  Can you prove it for any special cases?  Can you think of any other theorems that might be related or useful?  We're happy to help you understand concepts, but I'm not sure that proving theorems for you (or showing you the solution to exercises) will achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof for the following related result:

> A $d$-regular bipartite graph contains a perfect matching.

According to Hall's criterion, a perfect matching exists if for all $A \subseteq S$, $|N(A)| \geq |A|$. Take any $A \subseteq S$. There are $d|A|$ edges connecting vertices in $A$ to $T$. A given vertex $t \in T$ can be the target of at most $d$ such edges. Hence there are at least $d|A|/d = |A|$ such targets, that is, $|N(A)| \geq |A|$.

Try modifying this proof for your case.

Comment: In my case, |N(A)|=dG(s) and |A|=dG(t)? Can you be more specific about A?

Comment: I'm not going to solve the exercise for you. Try modifying what I wrote to your case.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I analysed what you said and I realised how to choose A. Right now I'm stuck at |N(A)|. Any hint about it?